# Check constraint to guarantee ltree ancestors

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints

I ran into an issue where we had a tree structure that looked like this:

```sql
select title, tree_path from my_table where tree_path <@ '3';

title    | tree_path
-----------------------
item A   | 3
item B   | 3.1.1
item C   | 3.1.2
item D   | 3.1.3
```

I somehow lost anything at 3.1 so all `tree_path <@ '3.1'` were orphaned.

Is there some sort of constraint I can write that would ensure that a node's ancestors exist?

Answer (score 5):

Since this is a tree structure, you can use a "parent" field with a FOREIGN KEY reference to the table itself, as described in [Adjacency list vs. nested sets](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/24/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-postgresql/) by Quassnoi.

For example, if you had another item `E` with `tree_path` = `3.1`, then the `parent` values of `B, C, D` would be `E`. The parent of `E` would be `A`. The parent of `A` would be `NULL`.

If you delete `E`, then enforcing the foreign key constraint would require a cascaded deletion of the children `B, C, D`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make the parent field a virtual field calculated off of the tree so I don't have to maintain the hierarchy in two places?

Comment: @lorddev I haven't used virtual fields myself, but I guess you can do the opposite -- make the `tree_path` a virtual field computed from `parent`. In the linked article, there are examples of how to find all ancestors of a particular node, which, if accumulated with an aggregate function, renders the path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily add a virtual or auto updated field, such as `parent_id`.

Assuming the numbers in your path are referencing the `id` column of the ltree table, so for a table with `id`, `title`, and `path` columns, you can add  `parent_id` with a trigger that can automatically keepit up to date. Then you can add a constraint on `parent_id` to `id` with `On Delete Restrict`.

Your trigger function would look like this:

```
BEGIN
  IF nlevel(new.path) > 1 then
    new.parent_id = ltree2text(subpath(new.path,-2,1))::bigint;
  end if; 
  RETURN NEW;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Paul's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/294337/227567), I used the following steps to solve this problem.

1. Add a generated column to keep track of the group's parent.

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table 
ADD COLUMN parent_path ltree GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    CASE 
        WHEN nlevel("tree_path") > 1 THEN subpath("tree_path", 0, nlevel("tree_path") - 1)
        ELSE NULL
    END
) STORED;
```

2. Created a foreign key constraint on that same column referencing the same table.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_my_table_parent FOREIGN KEY (parent_path) REFERENCES my_table("tree_path");
```